# Modify stream reader class to read from file instead of System.in

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a problem in time while reading from a file because I use in this case scanner.
I have a code fast input but without using a file 
so I want to add a file to my code or recommend to me a fast input method using file

```
public class FastReader {
    BufferedReader br;
    StringTokenizer st;

    public FastReader() {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    String next() {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    long nextLong() {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    double nextDouble() {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    String nextLine() {
        String str = "";
        try {
            str = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem? The reader is too slow (how slow?) reading what kind of data? How are you expecting the code to perform? Also, why the icc tag?

Comment: the actual problem is scanner is a very slow method but I know how to use it to read from a file. and I want to fast the code without file I use the code above and it fast the input but I didn't know how to read from a file with my fast code

Comment: To say that something is "fast" or "slow" you would need to measure it somehow. What performance are you aiming at and how is the code currently doing and with what data?

Comment: OK, maybe I understood your question now: You want to modify this `FastReader` class so that it can take input from a file instead of `System.in` as it's currently doing?

Comment: Yes this I want

Comment: So just add a `InputStream` parameter and pass a `FileInputStream` if you want.

Comment: can you explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments, you can modify the class to handle file input by adding a parameter to the constructor that allows injecting any `InputStream`:

```
public FastReader(InputStream in) {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
}
```

Then you can use the reader as follows:

```
FastReader systemInReader = new FastReader(System.in);
FastReader fileReader = new FastReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/the/file"));
```